# Querydsl null-safe concatenation

Tags: java, database, null, data-access-layer, querydsl

Suppose you have the following data in table corresponding to the class `Person`, what is the correct way to search null-safely for the concatenation of fields `name1` and `name2`?

```
@Entity
public class Person {
    Long id;
    String name1;
    String name2;
    // Getters and setters omitted for brevity
}
```

```
id |  name1  | name2   
------------------------
1  |  Foo    | null
2  |  null   | Bar
3  |  Foo    | Bar
```

By default the concatentation of two columns results in `null` if either is null.

```
public List<String> nameConcatenations() {
    JPAQuery q = new JPAQuery(entityManager);
    QPerson person = QPerson.person;
    StringExpression nameConcatenation = person.name1.concat(person.name2);
    return q.from(person).list(nameConcatenation)
}
```

The above code results in the following list:

```
null
null
FooBar
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One easy way is to use the SQL's `COALESCE` function which has an equivalent in Querydsl

```
public List<String> nameConcatenations() {
    JPAQuery q = new JPAQuery(entityManager);
    QPerson person = QPerson.person;
    StringExpression nameConcatenation = emptyIfNull(person.name1)
        .concat(emptyIfNull(person.name2));
    return q.from(person).list(nameConcatenation)
}

private static StringExpression emptyIfNull(StringExpression expression) {
    return expression.coalesce("").asString();
}
```

Will result in the following list:

```
Foo
Bar
FooBar
```